# JUnit test private method of GUI [JavaFX]

Tags: java, unit-testing, user-interface, javafx, junit

I have a `Controller` class in an JavaFX application. The class does many things. One of the things is to display list of files contained in some directory on a table. Only files with proper naming convention are diplayed on the table.

The `Controller` class contains a private method `filterByNamingConvention` that takes list of files and returns list of files that apply to the naming convention. The returned files are then displayed in table. There is no public method in the `Controller` class.

I want to make a unit test (using junit) of the filtering functionality, but the `filterByNamingConvention` method should remain private (so it can not be called outside the class). How can I implement this unit test? I would avoid the reflection pattern.

Would this method go to a library? But the method is only used once.

Here is part of the code:

```
    /**
     * File property change handler. On a directory path value change do change the textFieldDirPath text and update the table
     * @param dirPath path of the selected directory
     */
    private void handlefileProperty(String dirPath){
        textFieldDirPath.setText(dirPath);
        File dir = new File(dirPath);
        if(!dir.isDirectory()){
            //if the selected path isn't a directory, then show alert and return
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.setTitle("Warning Dialog");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("The passed file path: " + dir.getAbsolutePath() + " is not pointing to any directory.");
            alert.showAndWait();
            return;
        }

        List<FileModel> temporaryList = filterByNamingConvention(Arrays.asList(dir.listFiles()));
        filesList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(temporaryList);
        filesTable.setItems(filesList); //refresh table
        fileContentArea.setText("");    //clear the text area

        dirChooser.setInitialDirectory(dir);    //update initial directory
    }

    /**
     * filters all including files to only output list of those which apply to the convention criteria
     * X-yyyy-MM-dd-NoNN.suffix
     * @param files list of all files to be filtered
     * @return filtered list of file models
     */
    private static List<FileModel> filterByNamingConvention(List<File> files){
        /*
         * ^\\w+ means 1+ number of digits or letters or _ at the beginning of the string
         * \\d{4} means 4 digits
         * \\d+ means 1+ number of digits
         * \\w+$ means 1+ number of digits or letters or _ at the end of the string
         */
        final String pattern = "^\\w+-\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}-No\\d+.\\w+$";
        return files.stream()
                .filter(file -> file.getName().matches(pattern))
                .map(FileModel::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: Is there any public function that does little except calling handlefileProperty()? If so tou could unit test that function

Comment: Have you tried mockito and powermock?

Comment: the thing is that i am obligated to use junit